# relative navigation with GoTo metthod angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I can't navigate from one component to another using the navigateToOwnerTypePage() method.

thank you.

**nav.component.ts**

```
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  navigateToOwnerTypePage() {
    this._router.navigate(['/owner'], {relativeTo: this.route});
  }

}
```

**nav.component.html**

```
  <button class="button create-button" 
       (click)="navigateToOwnerTypePage()">Choisir</button>
```

**app.routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ChooseOwnerComponent } from './component/create-boat/owner-type/choose-owner/choose-owner.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'owner', component: ChooseOwnerComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
export const routingComponent = [ChooseOwnerComponent];
```

Comment: *the goTo() Angular method*? What is that?

Comment: sorry mistake, just goTo() method

Comment: And, where is that in your code?

Comment: with navigateToOwnerTypePage() sorry again

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: @DmitryS. no error but I would like the rendering of chooseOwnerComponent as I wrote the code I have the content of chooseOwnerComponent which is displayed at the bottom of my home page when I would like a new page.

I hope I was clear

Answer (score -1):

I solved my problem like this

**routing**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'owner', component: ChooseOwnerComponent},
  {path: 'home', component: HomepageComponent}
  
];
```

**html**

```
<header class="header-container">
    <app-nav></app-nav>
</header>
<app-table></app-table>
```